# Command not found after installing jRuby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am getting an issue trying to execute a command after installing a custom jRuby gem. In the gem I created, the Gemfile looks like below:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'archive-tar-minitar', '~> 0.5.2'
gem 'fastercsv', '~> 1.5.4'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2.2'
gem 'liquid', '>= 2.3.0'
gem 'net-sftp', '>=2.0.5'
gem 'net-ssh', '>=2.3.0'
gem 'jruby-openssl', '>=0.7.5'
gem 'crypt', '~>1.1.4'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.2'
```

and the .gemspec file:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "example/version"
require "rake"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name              = "example"
  s.version           = Example::VERSION
  s.platform          = 'java'
  s.date              = '2012-03-30'
  s.executables = ["load_csv_to_table"]

  s.rdoc_options      = ["--charset=UTF-8"]

  s.add_dependency('bundler', '~> 1.0')
  s.add_dependency('archive-tar-minitar', '~> 0.5.2')
  s.add_dependency('liquid', '>= 2.3.0')
  s.add_dependency('net-sftp', '>=2.0.5')
  s.add_dependency('net-ssh', '>=2.3.0')
  s.add_dependency('jruby-openssl', '>=0.7.5')
  s.add_dependency('crypt', '~>1.1.4')
  s.add_dependency('fastercsv', '~> 1.5.4')
  s.add_dependency('json', '~>1.6.6')
  s.add_dependency('nokogiri', '1.5.2')

  s.files = FileList['lib/**/*.rb', 'bin/*', 'vendor/java/**/*', 'resources/**/*'].to_a
  s.require_path    = ['lib']
  s.required_rubygems_version = ">= 1.3.4"
end
```

In the bin folder, I created a command called 'example':

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby

$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib') unless $:.include?(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib')

require 'example'
require 'pp'

pp "Example!!"
```

I installed the gem created in my local system with no errors (jruby -S gem install example-0.0.1-java.gem), but I when I try launch the command "example" the command doesn't seem to be found

Comment: How did you try to run `example`? What exactly was the error message?

Comment: Does the "example" command get installed as a bin file? If so, when you install the gem, does the "example" command file exist? By the way this line is not quite portable -- you may want to change it to be a specific manifest:   s.files = FileList['lib/**/*.rb', 'bin/*', 'vendor/java/**/*', 'resources/**/*'].to_a

Comment: yeah example should get installed as a bin file and yeah the command exists. How can I make that line more portable?

Comment: the error is "Command not found"